# How to edit NEXT button functionality in Umbraco

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco forms and umbraco inplement the Next button automatically, I want to know if there is an option to custome/edit the button's functionality, all I could change is the button's name at the config...

```
"datasource": null,
  "submitLabel": "good",
  "nextLabel": "Future",
  "prevLabel": "Past"
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: @Tim I want to use ajax functions instead of current functions which are postback

Comment: What version of Umbraco Forms are you using? Next button label is configurable in the form in backoffice.

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski I'm using 7.5.4

Comment: In forms settings you have something like this: https://d2ppvlu71ri8gs.cloudfront.net/items/1Y1Z2y1w2T1x3p0o272x/Image%202017-05-22%20at%2010.12.12%20AM.png?v=70459249

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the functionality when the user clicks the next button, then  you'll probably need a custom workflowtype. Here you can define the workflow that gets executed once the form is submitted

Documentation on how to implement a custom workflowtype
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/products/umbracoforms/developer/extending/adding-a-workflowtype